# Adding button on top of Imageview at runtime

Tags: android

I am creating a imageview at runtime and now want a add a button on top of the Imageview dynamically at run time and if I pan the image in the imageview the button in it should also pan accordingly. The problem is that Imageview does not allow to add subviews in it.

I am able to add the button on top of the imageview but when I pan the imageview the button remains constant in the screen. Any idea on how to do this? 
            Here is what I did:

```
        panImageView = new PanView(this); //Custom Imageview class to handle panning
        panImageView.setScaleType(ImageView.ScaleType.CENTER);
        //panimg.setAdjustViewBounds(true);

        FrameLayout mainRL = (FrameLayout) findViewById(R.id.mainRelativeLayout);
        mainRL.addView(panImageView);

        ImageWorker imgTask = new ImageWorker(panImageView, is);
        imgTask.execute(2000, 2000);


        //Start button
        Button startButton = new Button(this);

        int iRndBtn = R.drawable.round_button;
        startButton.setBackgroundResource(iRndBtn);

        startButton.getBackground().setColorFilter(Color.GREEN,PorterDuff.Mode.MULTIPLY);

        FrameLayout.LayoutParams layoutParams = new FrameLayout.LayoutParams(50, 50);
        //layoutParams.setMargins(intialPage.mapStartX, intialPage.mapStartY, 0, 0);
        layoutParams.setMargins(200, 200, 0, 0);
        startButton.setLayoutParams(layoutParams);
        //startButton.
        mainRL.addView(startButton,layoutParams);
```

Comment: What you have try ? Do some google before ask

Comment: First I created a custom Imageview which handles the panning, then I added the Button in the same Layout

Answer (score 0):

Add Image view first in any Layout and the add Button in that Layout.

Answer (score 0):

Use a RelativeLayout with the ImageView & button. set the button visibility to gone at start. When you need change the visibility.

Comment: I want the button to be visible all the time. I tried with RelativeLayout but it did not work :(

Comment: Just some code template: <RelativeLayout
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
>
<ImageView 
android:src="">
<Button android:text="">
</RelativeLayout>